# Issues with loading and viewing openstreetmap tiles : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 () ElectronReactWebpack

Tags: webpack, electron, leaflet, openstreetmap, react-leaflet

As I described in this `StackOverflow` question : [Leaflet : Suddenly I'm getting this error message: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71861153/leaflet-suddenly-im-getting-this-error-message-failed-to-load-resource-the?noredirect=1#comment126988321_71861153)
I'm experiencing issues with loading and viewing `openstreetmap tiles`  :

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()`

Based on the info here : https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/ the following are the requirements for the `openstreetmap` tiles usage:

```
Requirements

    Heavy use (e.g. distributing an app that uses tiles from openstreetmap.org) is forbidden without prior permission from the [Operations Working Group](https://wiki.osmfoundation.org/wiki/Operations_Working_Group). See below for alternatives.
    Clearly display [license](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/License) attribution.
    Do not actively or passively encourage copyright infringement.
    Calls to /cgi-bin/export may only be triggered by direct end-user action. (For example: “click here to export”.) The export call is an expensive (CPU+RAM) function to run and will frequently reject when server is under high load.
    Recommended: Do not hardcode any URL at tile.openstreetmap.org as doing so will limit your ability to react quickly if the service is disrupted or blocked.
    Recommended: add a link to https://www.openstreetmap.org/fixthemap to allow your users to report and fix problems in our data.

Technical Usage Requirements

    Valid [HTTP User-Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/en:User_agent) identifying application. Faking another app’s User-Agent WILL get you blocked.
    If known, a valid [HTTP Referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/en:HTTP_Referer).
    DO NOT send no-cache headers. (“Cache-Control: no-cache”, “Pragma: no-cache” etc.)
    Cache Tile downloads locally according to HTTP Expiry Header, alternatively a minimum of 7 days.
    Maximum of 2 download threads. (Unmodified web browsers’ download thread limits are acceptable.)

Note: modern web browsers in standard configuration generally pass all the above technical requirements.
```

As far as I understand, I do respect all of them

`html` file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="original-trial" content=AhRSNW+2zbXlDahhAcj194oqlgDxj3TqG4sYwhsUdqldtNbZagboEjqIJZuUvBsIjtij4VSW0YvP5tGSpVgu6wgAAABzeyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL2dnYy53b3JsZDo0NDMiLCJmZWF0dXJlIjoiVW5yZXN0cmljdGVkU2hhcmVkQXJyYXlCdWZmZXIiLCJleHBpcnkiOjE2MzM0NzgzO>
    <title>First Window</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="javascript" defer src="./app/index.js"></script>
    <script>
    </script>

    <style>
      .leaflet-container {
        height: 800px;
        width: 100%;
       }
     </style>

  </body>
</html>
```

`App.tsx` :

```
import * as React from 'react';

const Mapping = React.lazy(() => import('./mapVisualize/maps'))

function App() {

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <Mapping />
      </React.Suspense>

    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

`./mapVisualize/maps.js` :

import Leaflet from "leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

```
import React from "react";
import {
  TileLayer,
  LayersControl,
  Marker,
  Popup,
  MapContainer
} from "react-leaflet";


import iconUrl from "../../../assets/css/svg/push_pin_black_36dp.svg";

export const newicon = new Leaflet.Icon({
  iconUrl,
  iconAnchor: [5, 55],
  popupAnchor: [10, -44],
  iconSize: [25, 55]
});

const center = {
  lat: 51.505,
  lng: -0.09
};


export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MapContainer center={center} zoom={13} style={{ height: "200px" }}>
        <LayersControl position="topleft">
          <LayersControl.BaseLayer checked name="Basic Map">
            <TileLayer
              attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
              url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
          </LayersControl.BaseLayer>

          <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
            <Popup>
              A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
            </Popup>
          </Marker>

          <LayersControl.BaseLayer name="Topo Map">
            <TileLayer
              attribution='Map data: &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://viewfinderpanoramas.org">SRTM</a> | Map style: &copy; <a href="https://opentopomap.org">OpenTopoMap</a> (<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>)'
              url="https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
          </LayersControl.BaseLayer>
        </LayersControl>

          <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
            <Popup>
              A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
            </Popup>
          </Marker>

      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`webpack.config.js` :

```
const path = require('path');
const cwd = process.cwd();
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');


function srcPaths(src) {
  return path.join(__dirname, src);
}

const isEnvProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const isEnvDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

  // main process
var main_config = {
    mode: isEnvProduction ? 'production' : 'development',
    entry: './src/main/main.ts',
    target: 'electron-main',
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.jsx', '.js', 'ts'],
    },
    externals: [
      {
        'utf-8-validate': 'commonjs utf-8-validate',
        bufferutil: 'commonjs bufferutil',
      },
    ],
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          include: /src/,
          use: [{ loader: 'ts-loader' }]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(sass|less|css)$/i,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'style-loader'
            },
            {
              loader: 'css-loader'
            },
            {
              loader: 'less-loader',
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.s?css$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
              options: {
                sourceMap: true
              }
            },
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: true
              }
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: true
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpe?g|svg|gif)$/i,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "file-loader",
              options: {
                name: "[path]/[name].[ext]",
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.geojson$/,
           use: [
             {
               loader: "json-loader",
             }
          ],
        }
      ]
    },
    output: {
      path: __dirname + '/dist',
      filename: 'main.js'
    },
    node: {
      __dirname: false,
      __filename: false
    },
};

  // renderer process
var renderer_config =  {
    mode: isEnvProduction ? 'production' : 'development',
    entry: {
      app: ['./src/app/index.tsx', 'react-app-polyfill/stable'],
      style: [
        './src/app/styles/index.css',
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css')
      ]
    },
    //target: 'electron-renderer',
    //target: 'web',
    target: ['web', 'es5'],
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.jsx', '.js', '.tsx', '.ts'],
    },
    output: {
      path: __dirname + '/dist/',
        //filename: 'renderer.js'
      filename: '[name].js',
    },
    externals: [
      {
        'utf-8-validate': 'commonjs utf-8-validate',
        bufferutil: 'commonjs bufferutil',
      },
    ],
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|ts)x?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          },
        },
        {
          // css files
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'style-loader'
            },
            {
              loader: 'css-loader'
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpe?g|svg|gif)$/i,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "file-loader",
              options: {
                name: "[path]/[name].[ext]",
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          // Font files
          test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|otf)$/,
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[hash].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'dist/assets/css/'
          }
        },
      ],
    },
    node: {
      __dirname: false,
      __filename: false
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: './src/app/index.html',
        inject:'body',
        chunks: ['app'],
      }),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: '[name].css',
        chunkFilename: '[id].css',
        linkType: 'text/css',
      }),
      new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            from: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/assets/css"),
            to: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist/assets/css")
          },
        ],
        options: {
          concurrency: 100,
        },
      }),
    ]
}

module.exports = [
  main_config,
  renderer_config,
];
```

What perplex me is that this happens only for the `Basic Map Layer`:

```
    <LayersControl position="topleft">
      <LayersControl.BaseLayer checked name="Basic Map">
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
      </LayersControl.BaseLayer>
```

[image]

[image]

For example, it fails to load this tile:

https://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/13/4094/2723.png

[image]

Error message: `Access Denied See: https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/`

With the `Topo Map Layer` the visualization seems fine :

```
      <LayersControl.BaseLayer name="Topo Map">
        <TileLayer
          attribution='Map data: &copy; <a href="http://viewfinderpanoramas.org">SRTM</a> | Map style: &copy; <a href="https://opentopomap.org">OpenTopoMap</a> (<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>)'
          url="https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
      </LayersControl.BaseLayer>
```

[image]

How to solve the issue?
Looking forward to your kind help

Comment: @ghybs May I kindly ask you your expert advices?